# How to set ProgramID in Delphi 10.4.2

Tags: delphi, deployment

I want to (adhoc) deploy a Windows application using the MSIX features of Delphi. I successfully created a self-signed certificate, but when saving this, I get an error that the "ProgramID" cannot be left empty. I searched and searched, but can't find any place to fill in any such ID.

Could anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 3):

ProgramID is information that is stored in the executable as part of its Version Info.

You can edit the version information of your application in

Project Options -> Application -> Version Info

[image: Project Option Version Info]

Comment: Nice answer! You may want to add the fact that they should set the version info separately for each platform, not for "All Platforms", as version info isn't inherited from "All Platforms". This is described in the [Release Notes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Release_Notes)

Comment: Thank you. However, in my case there is no item "ProgramID" in the Version Info window.

Comment: Have you scrolled List of Keys all the way to the bottom. On older projects that have been created by older Delphi version `ProgramID` tends to be placed on last line. And even if for some reason it isn't added automatically you can always add a new key manually by right-clicking on Key list and choosing `Add Key`

Comment: I have now added the missing key and tried to get to deployement but I was not successful after hours of trying. It keeps coming with "[PAClient Error] Error: E5128 MakeAppx : error: Error info: error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 6, Column 13, Reason: '%projectName%' schendt pattern-beperking van '[-.A-Za-z0-9]+'."  And with "[PAClient Error] Error: E5128 Het kenmerk 'Name' met de waarde '%projectName%' kan niet worden geparseerd."

Comment: In Project/Options/Manifest I changed the default option "Auto generate" to "None". Thereafter the deployment runned without complaining. Is this OK or should I make a custom manifest file?

Comment: What is the name of your project? Based on your two last comments it seems that your project name contains unsupported character. Not all German characters are supported in project names.

Comment: Despite of frequent checks I see the comment of @SilverWarior only now. The name of my project has only A-Za-z characters in it (Dutch language, US international keyboard). Could you please comment on whether or not I should set up a custom manifest file or that I can leave the settings to "None"? I never before worked with manifests. Many thanks beforehead.

Comment: @JGMS Generally the manifest file that is generated by Delphi works just fine. Usually you see people making use of custom manifest files if they require manifest to enable some windows features that aren't supported by specific usually older Delphi version. Since you are using latest Delphi version I don't think that would be necessary. Could you provide the manifest file that Delphi creates to you so we can check its validity and integrity?

Comment: @Silverwarior, I have successfully generated a proper manifest file, after watching en excellent video of Olaf Monien (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODVHne9GOFY) on this subject. I found it rather complex because the debugger info was not really hinting in the right direction. Anyway, I managed to create a msix package, afterall. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JGMS So what is the diference between the manifest you made and the manifest Delphi created?